# Allocating values from one dataframe to another

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
OCC1990     Skilllevel
 3             1
 8             2
 12            2
 14            3
 15            1
```

As illustrated above it contains a long list of occupations assigned to a specific skill level.
My actual dataframe is a household survey with millions of rows, including a column which is also named `OCC1990`.
My goal is to implement my assigned skill levels from the above-listed data frame into the household survey.

I applied in the past already the following code for smaller dataframes, which is a pretty manual way

```
cps_data[cps_data$OCC1990  %in% 3,"skilllevel"] <- 1
cps_data[cps_data$OCC1990  %in% 4:7,"skilllevel"] <- 1
cps_data[cps_data$OCC1990  %in% 8,"skilllevel"] <- 2
```

But due to the fact that I don't wanna spend hours copying pasting as well as it increases the probability of making mistakes I'm searching for a different, more direct way.

I've already tried to merge both dataframes, but this result in an error related to the size of the vector.

Is there another way than merging just the two dataframes to assign the skill level also to the occupations in the survey?

Many thanks in advance
Xx freddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` for large dataset

create two vectors: `levels` and `labels`. The `levels` contains unique values of `OCC1990` and `labels` contains the new skill levels you want to apply.

Now use `levels` and `labels` inside the `factor` function to modify the skill level. (I used `Skilllevel` = 3 for `OCC1990` = 8 )

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
levels <- c(3:7,8)        # unique values of OCC1990
labels <- c(rep(1,5), 3)  # new Skill levels corresponding to OCC1990
setkey(df, OCC1990)       # sort OCC1990 for speed before filtering
df[ OCC1990 %in% levels, Skilllevel := as.integer(as.character(factor(OCC1990, levels = levels, labels = labels)))]
head(df)
#   OCC1990 Skilllevel
#1:       3          1
#2:       8          3
#3:      12          2
#4:      14          3
#5:      15          1
```

If you are still facing memory size issues, read in chunks of data from IO (use `fread`) and apply the above operation and then append data to a new file.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text='OCC1990     Skilllevel
 3             1
 8             2
 12            2
 14            3
 15            1 ', header=TRUE)
```